# Error in Function pointers with C++

Tags: c++

Why is the following code results in error :

```cpp
class A {

public:
        typedef void (A::*funptr)(void);

        void fun(void ) {
                cout << " Fun Call " <<endl;
        }

        void foo(void ) {
                cout << " Foo Call " <<endl;
        }

        funptr p[2];
        funptr q;

        A()
        {
                p[0]=&A::foo;
                p[1]=&A::fun;
                q   =&A::fun;
        }
};


int main ()
{

A obj;

(obj.*q)(void);

//(obj.p[0])();
//(obj.p[1])();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line and what's the error?

Comment: Because `cout` is undeclared. `#include <iostream>` and use `std::cout`. :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to call it like this:

```
(obj.*obj.q)();
```

The .* operator doesn't take a member name on the right-hand side, but rather an expression that evaluates to a member pointer.  When you write this:

```
(obj.*q)();
```

It is looking for a variable called q, but there is no such variable in scope.

Comment: works, but why does .*q does not points results in a member pointer. Can you throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change all occurrences of `(void)` to `()`. On the declarations it's redundant, and on the call itself it's not allowed.

Comment: This is true, but it should be a comment, rather than an answer.